# Summation of every row, column and diagonal in a 3x3 matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, pygame

My assignment is Tic-Tac_Toe using pygame and numpy. I Have almost all of the program done. I just need help understanding how to find if a winner is found. I winner is found if the summation of ANY row, column, or diagonal is equal to 3.

I have two 3x3 matrices filled with 0's. Let's call them xPlayer and oPlayer. The matrices get filled with 1 every time player x or player o chooses their choice at a certain location. So if, player x selects [0,0], the matrix location at [0,0] gets a 1 value. This should continue until the summation of any row, column, or diagonal is 3. If All the places in both the matrices are 1, then there is no winner.

I need help finding the winner. I'm really new to python so I don't know much about indexing though a matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Basically, how do you find out the summation of every row, column, and diagonal to check if ANY of them are equal to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To index a matrix in numpy, just use the notation A[y,x] to reference row y and column x of matrix A. If you would like to select multiple values from a matrix at once, you can use standard python list slicing. For example, to select the leftmost column of A you would use A[:,0].

In your case, to find the sum of the columns you could do

```
sum(xPlayer[:,0])
```

to calculate the sum of the leftmost column of xPlayer and

```
sum(xPlayer[0,:])
```

for the top row of xPlayer. In the case of diagonals, you will just need to manually add the array entries, so one of the diagonals would be:

```
xPlayer[0,0]+xPlayer[1,1]+xPlayer[2,2]
```

Alternatively, you could use numpy functions to calculate the sums over the rows and columns where

```
xPlayer.sum(0)
```

calculates the sum across the rows in each column and

```
xPlayer.sum(1)
```

calculates the sum across the columns in each row. You could even calculate the diagonals without manually specifying the indices, so

```
sum(xPlayer.diagonal())
```

for the top left-bottom right diagonal and

```
sum(numpy.fliplr(xPlayer).diagonal())
```

for the other diagonal.

Edit: To clarify, this applies to "arrays" in numpy. All of the above statements can still be used for "matrices" by either converting the matrix to an array by

```
arr = numpy.array(mat)
```

or by using the resulting matrix appropriately. Note that in the latter case, the matrix will not have the same shape for all operations.

Comment: Wow this is really easy. I feel extremely stupid. I should have looked for in depth. Thank you for your help

Comment: ` index a matrix in numpy` did you mean  `index a *array* in numpy`

Answer (score -2):

set a bool to checks every turn if someone has won. if it returns true, then whosever turn it is has won

so, for instance, it is x turn, he plays the winning move, bool checks if someone has won,returns true, print out (player whose turn it is) has won! and end game.

Comment: The Winner is determined by the summation of ANY row, column, or diagonal. If any of these equals 3, then the winner is chosen. I could implement what you said but it wouldn't help me understand how to find the summation of every row, column and diagonal to check if any of them are equal to 3.